# Kerning and ligatures in TeX without TeX

Tags: luatex, fontspec, ligatures, kerning, luaotfload

I am trying to get the same output as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126712/48028) by topskip (an extended version with comments is presented in the [TeX without TeX article](http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php?title=TeX_without_TeX&oldid=173)). I am getting a paragraph consisting of 6 lines with hyphenation, but kerning and ligatures are lost (turned off?) as it can be seen around the character **V** in VLTAVA and in the letters **ffi** in office.

I use WinXP + TeX Live 2014 and Lubuntu 13.10 + TeX Live 2013. I've got the same output, the font is `LinLibertine_R.otf`.

First tip by topskip is to skip loading of the `fontspec` package which could handle things differently than the `luaotfload` package. Therefore, instead of `libertine` and `luatextra` (they both load the `fontspec` package), I tried to load `luacode` and `luaotfload` packages directly, no success, no errors and no warnings. Where the problem might be?

We run `lualatex testfonts.tex`.

```
% lualatex testfonts.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
%\usepackage{luatextra}
%\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{luaotfload}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}
\font\main={file:LinLibertine_R.otf}
\main

\begin{luacode*}
function count_lines (head)
  local linecount = 0
  while head do
    if head.id == 0 then linecount = linecount + 1 end
    head = head.next
  end
  return linecount
end

function mknodes( text )
  local current_font = font.current()
  local font_parameters = font.getfont(current_font).parameters
  local n, head, last
  -- we should insert the paragraph indentation at the beginning
  head = node.new("glue")
  head.spec = node.new("glue_spec")
  head.spec.width = 20 * 2^16
  last = head

  for s in string.utfvalues( text ) do
    local char = unicode.utf8.char(s)
    if unicode.utf8.match(char,"%s") then
      -- its a space
      n = node.new("glue")
      n.spec = node.new("glue_spec")
      n.spec.width   = font_parameters.space
      n.spec.shrink  = font_parameters.space_shrink
      n.spec.stretch = font_parameters.space_stretch
    else -- a glyph
      n = node.new("glyph")
      n.font = current_font
      n.subtype = 1
      n.char = s
      n.lang = tex.language
      n.uchyph = 1
      n.left = tex.lefthyphenmin
      n.right = tex.righthyphenmin
    end

    last.next = n
    last = n
  end

  -- now add the final parts: a penalty and the parfillskip glue
  local penalty = node.new("penalty")
  penalty.penalty = 10000

  local parfillskip = node.new("glue")
  parfillskip.spec = node.new("glue_spec")
  parfillskip.spec.stretch = 2^16
  parfillskip.spec.stretch_order = 2

  last.next = penalty
  penalty.next = parfillskip

  -- just to create the prev pointers for tex.linebreak
  node.slide(head)
  return head
end

local txt = "VLTAVA office A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine."

tex.baselineskip = node.new("glue_spec")
tex.baselineskip.width = 14 * 2^16

local head = mknodes(txt)
lang.hyphenate(head)
head = node.kerning(head)
head = node.ligaturing(head)

local vbox
local size = 90
lines = 0
lines_goal = 6

while lines < lines_goal do
  texio.write_nl(string.format("Formatting text to %d mm",size))
  local copy_of_head = node.copy_list(head)
  vbox = tex.linebreak(copy_of_head,{ hsize = tex.sp(string.format("%dmm",size))})
  size = size - 10
  lines = count_lines(vbox)
  texio.write_nl(string.format("lines=%d",lines))
end

node.write(vbox)
\end{luacode*}

VLTAVA office
\end{document}
```

[image: a preview of the result]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For opentype fonts, `luaotfload` provide function `nodes.simple_font_handler` which will take care of all font manipulations like ligaturing and kerning and all other features supported by `luaotfload`. This function isn't advertised in the manual, I've found it in `luaotfload` source code. It is called as node callback on normal text, but as you create nodes directly from Lua, it doesn't take effect on your text and you have to call it explicitly:

```lua
local head = mknodes(txt)
lang.hyphenate(head)
head = nodes.simple_font_handler(head)
```

you don't have to call `node.ligaturing` and `node.kerning` any more, they were called from `simple_font_handler` already

[image]

Comment: A small question from a person with no experience in the lua part of `luaTeX`. Isn't better to call first `simple_font_handler` and latter `hyphenate`? I wil guess that kerning and ligature adjustment will change the width of words; and, therefore, potentially the best hyphenation.

Comment: @zunbeltz `hyphenate` just insert marks on potential hyphenation points, actual breaking into lines happens later, after all node manipulations

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Does the insertion of a potential hyphenation point prevent ligatures? For example the insertion of hyphenations points `dif•fi•cult` does not block the use of ff ligature if the word is not hyphenated, does it?

Comment: @zunbeltz no, it doesn't prevent ligatures :)